# Column in extended table are not presented in form data on Eclipse Scout

Tags: extends, form-data, eclipse-scout

I have Table field as Templates.

For this Table field I have form data created with anotation

```
@FormData(value = AbstractMyTableData.class, sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.USE, defaultSubtypeSdkCommand = FormData.DefaultSubtypeSdkCommand.CREATE)
public abstract class MyTableField extends AbstractTableField<MyTableField.Table>
```

Inside MyTableField.Table I have `n` column and all of them is presented in form data for this field, so I can add rows like :

```
int rowNum = formData.addRow();
formData.setColumn_1(rowNumber, value);
....
formData.setColumn_n(rowNumber, value);
```

Now I want to extend my table so instead of :

```
public class Table extends AbstractExtensibleTable {
```

I now have

```
public class Table extends AbstractTreeTable {
```

AbstractTreeTable is template from this [link](https://gist.github.com/jmini/ce73b04089bc56f569d0/download#).

It has two new columns inside. My problem is that inside AbstractMyTableData there is still only `n` columns and not those two. So when I create new row by `addRow` I can't set those two values to the row.

Pleas help.

---

Additional

I did't see that `AbstractTableFieldBeanData` is not just random class name like `AbstractMyTableFieldData`, but create different kind of form data.

Now I have bean based table data.

But my problem remain. Even in new bean based data, there is just columns from myTable and not from treeTable.

My hierarchy is like @Jmini described.

```
AbstractTable
|   (no columns defined as inner class)
|
\---AbstractTreeTable
    |   (2 columns defined as inner class: ParentKeyColumn and KeyColumn)
    |
    \---MyTableField.Table
         (additional columns defined as inner class)
```

This `MyTableField.Table` is inside `MyTableField` witch is template.

So my code looks like this :

```
@FormData(sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.CREATE, value = AbstractTableFieldBeanData.class, defaultSubtypeSdkCommand = FormData.DefaultSubtypeSdkCommand.CREATE)
public abstract class MyTableField extends
AbstractTableField<MyTableField.Table> {
....
    @Order(10.0)
    public class Table extends AbstractTreeTable {
```

in `AbstractTreeTable` I don't have any annotation  like @Jmini suggest.

I add rows like :

```
 MyTableFieldRowData row = formData.addRow();
 row.setColumn1(value);
```

but inside `MyTableFieldRowData` there is no additional rows from `AbstractTreeTable`

Have I miss something ?

Comment: Bug 459496 (based on the input of this question) was fixed and is available on the mars nightly build. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=459496

Answer (score 0):

## Array based TableData:

If you methods like this in the FormData:

```
LoremTable table = formData.getLoremTable();
int r = table.addRow();
table.setAaaa(r, "Hello world");
table.setBbbb(r, 42);
```

You are using [Array based TableData](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/TableData#Array_based_TableData).

---

## Bean based TableData:

If you methods like this in the FormData:

```
IpsumTable table = formData.getIpsumTable();
IpsumTableRowData rowData = table.addRow();
rowData.setAaaa("Hello world");
rowData.setBbbb(42);
```

You are using [Bean based TableData](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/TableData#Bean_based_TableData).

---

## Your case:

To summarize your case, you have a TableField with a Table having a complex inheritance graph looking like that:

```
AbstractTable
|   (no columns defined as inner class)
|
\---AbstractTreeTable
    |   (2 columns defined as inner class: ParentKeyColumn and KeyColumn)
    |
    \---MyTableField.Table
            (additional columns defined as inner class)
```

You will need **bean based table data**, because with array based table data, the SDK will only consider the columns of `MyTableField.Table` to generate the formData. With bean based table data you will get all the columns you expect.

---

A possible way to solve your problem, is to change the generated table data in the formData. This is configured on the table field class in the form.

Check the type hierarchy of your table field class:

```
AbstractTableField (defined in the scout jar -> you can not modify it)
|   
\---MyTableField
```

The SDK checks the `FormData` annotation down the type hierarchy.

With Scout Version smaller than 4.2, `AbstractTableField` is configured to use array based table data. With version bigger than 4.3 it is configured to use bean based table data.

At each level you can define something else. For example at `MyTableField` level. You can do something like that:

```
@FormData(sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.USE, value = AbstractTableFieldBeanData.class, defaultSubtypeSdkCommand = FormData.DefaultSubtypeSdkCommand.CREATE)
public class MyTableField extends AbstractTableField<MyTableField.Table>
```

This will change the generated code.

---

On the wiki you can read additional examples. For example is you have something like:

```
AbstractTableField 
|
\---AbstractMyAppTableField
    |
    \---MyTableField
```

You can define the table data you want at `AbstractMyAppTableField`. If all your table field extends `AbstractMyAppTableField` (which is a recommended practice), with one single config you can change all the table data of your application and you ensure that each developer will use the same pattern.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your setup (explained in the "additional" section of your question). I think you have found a bug, and I opened it here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=459496 A workaround is also provided in the Bug description. Thank you for the time you took to explain your case.