# bean array eclipse scout sample

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-scout

I am learning Eclipse Scout... I have connected to Sql server, fetching data using Object[][]...now, I want to fetch data using beans, beanarray holder...
I dont know the process...

I have created bean Users!
I have populated bean using service, using this example: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/310526/

So can someone explain how to use beans in scout, to populate table, or form...

1. Make a bean example: users
2. Fill the bean in service example: get user data from users table
3. populate table using that bean...

tnx

Answer (score 0):

## Java POJO (bean)

If you are working with plain old java object (POJO) like this:

```
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

You can populate an array of those POJO like this:

```
public User[] loadAll() throws ProcessingException {
  BeanArrayHolder<User> beansArray = new BeanArrayHolder<User>(User.class);

  SQL.selectInto(" select first_name, last_name " +
      " from users " +
      " into :{FirstName}, :{LastName} ", beansArray);

  return beansArray.getBeans();
}
```

To populate your table, you need to do it by hand. For example on the client side:

```
for (User user : beansArray.getBeans()) {
  ITableRow row = getTable().createRow();
  getTable().getNameColumn().setValue(row, user.getLastName());
  getTable().getFirstNameColumn().setValue(row, user.getFirstName());
  getTable().addRow(row, true);
}
```

A mapping server side is also possible. But in this case, you should definitively consider to use table data (see the next section)

---

## Table data

You should ensure that you are using bean based TableData. Read this answer to know how you can differentiate [table based TableData and bean based TableData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28363618/91497).

Assuming you have a UserTableField like this in your Form:

```
@Order(10.0)
@FormData(sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.USE, value = AbstractTableFieldBeanData.class, defaultSubtypeSdkCommand = FormData.DefaultSubtypeSdkCommand.CREATE)
public class UserTableField extends AbstractTableField<UserTableField.Table> {

  @Order(10.0)
  public class Table extends AbstractExtensibleTable {

    public LastNameColumn getLastNameColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(LastNameColumn.class);
    }

    public FirstNameColumn getFirstNameColumn() {
      return getColumnSet().getColumnByClass(FirstNameColumn.class);
    }

    @Order(10.0)
    public class FirstNameColumn extends AbstractStringColumn {

      @Override
      protected String getConfiguredHeaderText() {
        return TEXTS.get("FirstName");
      }
    }

    @Order(20.0)
    public class LastNameColumn extends AbstractStringColumn {

      @Override
      protected String getConfiguredHeaderText() {
        return TEXTS.get("LastName");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to do something like that in your service:

```
UserTableRowData rowData = formData.getUserTable().addRow();
rowData.setFirstName("John");
rowData.setLastName("Smith");
```

Instead of adding the rows manualy, if you want to have a SQL query to populate the table, you can do something like that:

```
BeanArrayHolder<User> beansArray = new BeanArrayHolder<User>(User.class);

SQL.selectInto(" select first_name, last_name " +
      " from users " +
      " into :{UserTable.FirstName}, :{UserTable.LastName} ", formData);
```

It works the same way for TablePageData, see an example in our tutorial:

[MiniCrm Tutorial > Write the first page > Load data on the server](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Tutorial/4.0/Minicrm/Write_the_first_page#Load_data_on_the_server)

Comment: Hi, I have tried! But no luck! Dont know where to call the bean, I have added @FormData(sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.USE, value = AbstractTableFieldBeanData.class, defaultSubtypeSdkCommand = FormData.DefaultSubtypeSdkCommand.CREATE)
to class UsersTableData, created Bean, filled it with select, but no luck!

Comment: The line `@FormData(sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.USE, value = AbstractTableFieldBeanData.class, defaultSubtypeSdkCommand = FormData.DefaultSubtypeSdkCommand.CREATE)` goes on the table field, not on the table data class.

Comment: I am not sure to know how I can help you, because I do not understand what you do not get. Feel free to continue the discussion I will do my best.